# 'invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Google Translation Api

Tags: python, django, api, cloud

when I am trying to run this on my server I am getting following error but is working on my local machine.

```
RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe.
 Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether correct time is configured in the server. Mostly this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, If a particular answer is helpful in solving your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark next to it.